# Hibernate: can I define a OneToOne relationship that takes place only if the target entity does exists?

Tags: hibernate

I am having troubles loading an entity that contains an optional one-to-one relationship with another entity.

When I try to load an entity with the corresponding mapping everything seems to be ok, but sometimes (I guess it is when I try to load a `CitationInformation` without the corresponding `VenueTopic`) I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of
```

These are my classes:

```
@Entity
public class CitationInformation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long identifier;

    private String doi;

    @OneToOne(optional = true, targetEntity = VenueTopic.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "venue")
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private String venue;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class VenueTopic {
    @Id
    private String venueName;
    private String topic;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately I need to deal with this dirty situation because I had to integrate my hibernate entities with data from another table that was not generated through hibernate.

I think I messed something up in the `@OneToOne` relationship. I am not sure I defined correctly the fact that it is optional and how I want missing values to me handled.

The behavior I want is that `CitationInformation` should always contain a `venue`, but the relationship should exist *only* if there is a `VenueTopic` entity with the same `venueName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing private String venue in your class CitationInformation from type String to type VenuTopic might solve the problem. I do not understand why you are using type string when you are already mapping it to another entity.

Comment: My problem is that I had to extend the database. In the previous version using the string did make sense.

What would you recommend me to go as smoothly as possible with the migration process?

Comment: After a little experimenting I managed to fix my issue. Thanks a lot for your suggestion!